# Magento 2 - Passing Store Variables To Block From Layout XML File

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2, is it possible to pass store information variables to a block through layout XML and display information like the store's phone number?

Something like this:

```html
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header.contact.block" template="Magento_Theme::html/contact-phone.phtml">
   <arguments>
       <argument name="phone" translate="true" xsi:type="string">{{config path="general/store_information/phone"}}</argument>
   </arguments>
</block>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a block that returns a Array + email :

```
    class StoreInfo extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_storeInformation;
    protected $_scopeConfig;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\Information $storeInformation,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->_storeInformation = $storeInformation;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function getStoreInformationObject()
    {
        $ret = $this->_storeInformation->getStoreInformationObject($this->_storeManager->getStore());
        $data = $ret->getData();
        $data['email'] = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'trans_email/ident_sales/email',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
        return $data;
    }
}
```

More on my [gitHub](https://github.com/silici0/StoreInfo)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than extending `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` you'd better use `view model`

[Magento DevDocs -> View Model](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/view-models.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variable within block like this.

```
<action method="setData"><name>category_id</name><value>3</value></action>
```